# DES encryption in OFB mode in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, des

This is my current implementation of the Data Encryption Standard algorithm in .NET, both encryption and decryption:

```cs
static string Encrypt(string text, string key)
        {
            byte[] textBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            byte[] keyBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

            DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

            provider.Mode = CipherMode.OFB;

            ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, keyBytes);
            CryptoStreamMode mode = CryptoStreamMode.Write;

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, mode);
            cryptoStream.Write(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            memoryStream.Read(encryptedTextBytes, 0, encryptedTextBytes.Length);

            string encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedTextBytes);

            return encryptedText;
        }

static string Decrypt(string text, string key)
        {
            byte[] textBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
            byte[] keyBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

            DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

            provider.Mode = CipherMode.OFB;

            ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, keyBytes);
            CryptoStreamMode mode = CryptoStreamMode.Write;

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, mode);
            cryptoStream.Write(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            byte[] decryptedMessageBytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            memoryStream.Read(decryptedMessageBytes, 0, decryptedMessageBytes.Length);

            string decryptedText = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedMessageBytes);

            return decryptedText;
        }
```

But it returns exception: `OFB is not supported by this implementation`.
Any ideas how to fix it, or where to find working OFB implementation?

Comment: Is not supported as far as I know, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4252411/9014097) (although quite old) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15771) (actually concerning CFB, but OFB is also briefly mentioned). But you could use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/). Btw, DES is outdated and insecure.

Comment: @Topaco it's not for practical use, but for science. I need DES specifically running in OFB mode.